# how to make specific application window as active window using autoIt script?

Tags: autoit

Many applications are running in my system. I need to bring specific application window as an active window. From my knowledge this will be done by shell script that's why i am choosing AutoIt script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at the helpfile.
WinActivate, Winexists ...

```
#include<Array.au3>
$a = ProcessGetId('firefox.exe')
For $i = 1 To UBound($a) - 1
    ConsoleWrite(ProcessGetWindow($a[$i]) & @CRLF)
Next

Func ProcessGetWindow($PId)
    If IsNumber($PId) = 0 Or ProcessExists(ProcessGetName($PId)) = 0 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $WinList = WinList()
        Local $i = 1
        Local $WindowTitle = ""
        While $i <= $WinList[0][0] And $WindowTitle = ""
            If WinGetProcess($WinList[$i][0], "") = $PId Then
                $WindowTitle = $WinList[$i][0]
            Else
                $i += 1
            EndIf
        WEnd
        Return $WindowTitle
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetWindow

Func ProcessGetId($Process)
    If IsString($Process) = 0 Then
        SetError(2)
    ElseIf ProcessExists($Process) = 0 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $PList = ProcessList($Process)
        Local $i
        Local $PId[$PList[0][0] + 1]
        $PId[0] = $PList[0][0]
        For $i = 1 To $PList[0][0]
            $PId[$i] = $PList[$i][1]
        Next
        Return $PId
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetId

Func ProcessGetName($PId)
    If IsNumber($PId) = 0 Then
        SetError(2)
    ElseIf $PId > 9999 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $PList = ProcessList()
        Local $i = 1
        Local $ProcessName = ""

        While $i <= $PList[0][0] And $ProcessName = ""
            If $PList[$i][1] = $PId Then
                $ProcessName = $PList[$i][0]
            Else
                $i = $i + 1
            EndIf
        WEnd
        Return $ProcessName
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetName
```